# How do I fix the display of reledmac critical notes registers to the bottom of the page?

Tags: reledmac, vertical-spacing, footmisc

Dear fellow TeXnicians,

when using reledmac, I would like to make a global adjustment to the four registers (A,B,C,D) of critical notes to appear fixed on the bottom of the page, so that, for consistency's sake, they behave as footnotes do when given the command \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}. The whitespace should thus be between the main body of the text and the registers, rather than below the registers.

Is there such a global option? I am not sure how to use footnoterule, that seems to be the nearest equivalent ...

Thanks for your help

Comment: What about `\vfill\doendnotes{A}` ?

Comment: Thank you Pieter! I have just seen that I made an inadvertent error, I am trying to define the critical notes - not the endnotes - which accompany the main body of the work. Sorry, and thank you for your input

Comment: I see in all examples that the critical notes are in fact on the bottom of the page with white space between the main text and the notes if the page is not full. See the examples in `.../doc/latex/reledmac/examples/` in your TeX distribution. Do you have an example where this is not happening?

Comment: Thank you for your help and concern. In that case, it might be caused by geometry, footmisc, or any other incompatibility. Given that the thesis I am writing has a complex preamble, it might be overburdening everyone to provide it in full...